# How to pull first 6 characters from variable input using Shell Script

Tags: shell, shell-script, automator

I am running a shell script in Mac automator. I no very little about this type of sripting. Basically just found something I could use from other sources.
How do I make this line

```
mkdir "$1_"$(date -j +"%m%y")
```

only use the first 6 characters in the `$1` content? For example, the user inputs text like `123456Description` in to the first variable.
I want it to remove `Description`, which could be any text, and only pick out the first 6 digits in the entry.

Full Shell script is this:

```
mkdir -p "$1 $(date -j +"%m%y")/info"
rm -r "$1"
mkdir "${1:0:6}_"$(date -j +"%m%y")
```

Comment: What command interpreter did you specify in your script? `#!/bin/sh`? `#!/bin/bash`? `#!/usr/bin/zsh`?

Comment: I used bin/bash just because that was the sample I saw that I was following.

Comment: If you have problems with the proposed solution, [edit] your question and add more details. Show how your script is called, maybe show more code.

Comment: Please also show what parameter is passed to the script. You could add a line `echo "<$1>"` to do this. And add a line `set -x` before the first `mkdir` line to print all commands that get executed.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you could use

```
mkdir "${1:0:6}_"$(date -j +"%m%y")
```

See section **Variable expansion / Substring replacement** in
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 10. Manipulating Variables](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: I am getting this error? Do you know what it means?

Comment: The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “mkdir: /Users_0123: Read-only file system”

Comment: @Denise it means what is says: you're trying (and failing) to create the directory `/Users_0123` because it's on a read-only filesystem. Read-only means you can't write to it. Choose a different path to create the directory

Comment: @roaima I was confused by that error since it creates the first folder with no problems.
Here is the full content I am trying to do.
mkdir -p "$1 $(date -j +"%m%y")/info"
rm -r "$1"
mkdir "${1:0:6}_"$(date -j +"%m%y")

I don't understand this part: ${1. How does it know what that first argument is supposed to be?

Comment: Denise please add this to your question. Put everything in the one place so that it's easy for people who want to help you to read and understand (and format the code with the `{}` button) to it's obvious it's code

Comment: I am using a shell script in automator on a mac. unfortunately I dont see a place to add a screen shot of the entire automator action.